# How to install PIL with Freetype?

Tags: django, captcha, python-imaging-library, freetype2

I wanted to put django-simple-captcha in my project but it cannot create images for the CaptchaField. It says "No module named _imagingft"

I am using Ubuntu 11.04

I installed libfreetype6 and libfreetype6-dev by apt-get install

then I downloaded PIL 1.1.6 and changed

```
FREETYPE_ROOT = "/usr/local/include"
```

then I built PIL

```
python setup.py build
```

then install it

```
python setup.py install
```

I still cannot import _imagingft and my page still does not display the captcha image. it only shows

```
captcha <input box>
```

Comment: OK it works now, all I did was to redo everything and not install zlib,jpeglib,freetype via aptitude

Comment: As this is an answer, you should post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

OK it works now, all I did was to redo everything and not install zlib,jpeglib,freetype via aptitude

Sorry I posted it as comment, I didn't knew I can already answer my own question.